# Adding node fields in page manager

Tags: 8, panels

I'm using D8 and the [page_manager](https://www.drupal.org/project/page_manager) and [panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) modules. I've used the D7 equivalents before and it's been easy to add a specific field for a node to the content section of a panel.

However in D8 when I try and add the fields there are no options that come up in the content section for specific fields.  The only node related option I see is for whole entities and their display modes.

Is there another module that I need to enable to get the individual fields from a node like in D7?

Comment: try this https://www.drupal.org/project/fieldblock